# Changing Buttons color for Online examination

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a online examination system and I have to change the color of buttons like the images in the link how can I do it?

**Example:** If user Clicks on save $ next color change into green like wise. should I use jquery?
and also I have to convert the questions "Hindi to English" or "English to Hindi" by the dropdownlist while taking examination.

Please check the image you will understand me better

http://www.ginfoworld.com/sdf.png

http://www.ginfoworld.com/Untitled.png

**Note**: I'am using Datalist to show questions. I am saving answers into db. I have question in both languages hindi and Englsh.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use:

```
Button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
```

For changing language on drop down selection, make 2 asp:Panels for hindi and english (2 languages) and you can set its visibility on drop down change.

Following link will better guid you for this purpose:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_panel_controls.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```

Comment: I'll have 200 buttons and 200 questions I am displaying question in datalist. how will I bind them? means if user click on question no 12 the buttons color would be change into green.